# Fetch SMTP, Username Info from a Windows Machine & Email everytime a .bat file is run

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

We use batch scripts to apply changes to our desktop software for all our clients with each client having 40-50 software users atleast. Any configuration change in our software is done by us and we create a self extracting exe using a batch script which copies the changed configuration files on users machine. All they need to do is double click on this exe.

Now, we have no ways of telling whether our clients (users or their IT department) have applied the patch or not and so i would like to add few extra line of code in our existing batch file which should do the following:

1. Intimate us by emailing us when our patch is applied by the clients.

I have no idea how would i do this in batch but it will be great if i could do it. My understanding is that we need to fetch following info from client network/machine.

```
1. SMTP Server Details
2. Username (from under c:\users\ folder) may be i am not sure if it could be fetched from anywhere else? This so that we know which client of ours has run the patch.   
3. Emails it to us.
```

Can you please advise?

Note: I only know very basic batch scripting.

Comment: You can use `%username%` to get the username of the current user.

Comment: @DennisvanGils Thanks Dennis. The scope of this question is however much larger. Looking for a complete solution.

Comment: That's why I left this as a comment and not an answer. You should also put a bit more effort into your questions. What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is a site to help people with their code, not a free coding service.

Comment: And i know that, there is no need to be aggressive !! You can choose not to reply to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: my apologies if my comment sounded aggressive, it wasn't meant that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gail.com"

emailObj.To       = "dc@gail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration
msgbox emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "YourUserName"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Password1"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done
```

If not set in code the email details are taken from Outlook Express or Windows Mail's default account, but not Mail in Windows 8 or 10 where you must know them. And that's the problem as you can't know their password, server, or username. However YOU can send the mail as you using your email server. You may need to configure your mail server and/or firewall to allow external sending of mail.

Comment: Thanks @Noodles, i will give this a go and will get back to you. Its a shame that this wouldn't work in Windows 8 or 10 given that a lot of our clients have already moved to Win 8/10 :(. But still thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: when i try to save the above in a .bat file and run it, it just comes up with loads of "not recognized as an internal or external command" errors.

Comment: Its VBScript. Put into a VBS file. This is the help file. https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

Comment: `start "" "mailto:you@gmail.com?body=%username%&subject=%userdomain%"` is the best you can do in batch. They have to click send.

Comment: Hi, It looks like this will work if we provide all the info but since we have got multiple clients which are under their own networks this might not be a feasible solution to our requirement. Any suggestions on how we can automate stuff to know that a client has run our patch? We would like our batch script to intimate us in some way if not emails.

Comment: The normal way is to have a web server taking calls from your script (it needs to be vbs). Web traffic isn't blocked so side steps security (like email prevention). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest. Your web server application logs the info.

Comment: Thanks Noodles, i guess i will try something with VB.